# Adding values to scalar list whilst under 'while' loop

Tags: perl, csv

Could someone please explain how I can add values to a scalar list as I'm reading them in from a csv file?

Code is the following:

```
open (IN, $infile) || die "Cannot open $infile\n";
my ($x,$y);

while (my $line = <IN>){
    chomp ($line);
    my @temp = split (/,/,$line);
    $x .= $temp[0].",";
    $y .= $temp[1].",";
}

$x = [$x];
$y = [$y];
close (IN);
```

This does work and put it in a list, BUT not value by value, but rather all values combined as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly more elegant; doesn't require cluttering your namespace with two superfluous variables.

```
my ($xs, $ys) = ([], []);
while(my $line = <IN>) { #Note: don't use bare filehandles like this. (See below)
    chomp $line;
    my ($x, $y) = split /,/, $line;
    push @$xs, $x;
    push @$ys, $y;
}

#done
```

Bare filehandles are a bad idea. Use lexical filehandles. (And 3-arg open!). Lexical file handles auto-close when they go out of scope. See [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).

```
open FH, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!\n"; #Bad
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!\n"; #Better
```

Comment: Actually, it creates exactly as many "intermediate" arrays at exactly the same location. The only thing you changed is where you create references to those arrays. Your choice results in the addition of two needless dereferences per input line.

Comment: @ikegami Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: You said, "needless dereferences"; I take that to mean that you object to the (insignificant) performance overhead; surely you aren't objecting to them on the grounds of clarity?

Comment: Exactly. Suggesting avoiding intermediate arrays (which you didn't even end up doing) is not something you should have done.

Comment: @ikegami Anyway, I rephrased the explanation to be more clear. I consider ANY variable intermediate if it's just used to generate a reference, even if it doesn't cause duplication of contents in memory.

Comment: It's called code reduction. It's "a root of computer science", so to speak.

Comment: It's not used just to generate a reference. It's used to hold the values. EXACTLY like the arrays you created.

Comment: `my $xs = \@xs;` -- the end goal of the code is to generate a scalar reference to an array; that means that making the code create arrayrefs in the first place is vastly clearer in intent than reaching over one's shoulder to scratch one's ass by first creating a named array variable, populating that, and then discarding it in lieu of a reference thereunto. How in the world could having two deceptively similarly named variables with the same contents EVER have ANY benefit of any kind?

Comment: Poppycock. The intent of the code is to extract data from the file. References have nothing to do with the goal at all. Assuming there's a reason references are used here at all, the reason is to permit passing the arrays to a sub or returning the arrays from a sub. The references are not part of the goal at all. By your own argument, they should not be used where you used them. Separate your concerns. Returning a value has nothing to do with parsing a file.

Comment: Re "How in the world could having two deceptively similarly named variables with the same contents EVER have ANY benefit of any kind?" Yeah, I think it's silly that he actually stored those in variables. The last two line of my code should be inlined two whatever line follows (e.g. `return \@xs, \@ys;` or `foo(\@xs, \@ys)`). (Incidentally, that means I have exactly the same number of named variables as you do, so the comment in your updated answer is no better. And you still have the needless complexities that keep it from being its most inelegant. Beauty is when you can't take anything away.)

Comment: And that's your problem-- you're assuming way too much. The question is how to add values to [an array ref]; there is **NO** indication of the context. So DON'T assume the refs will immediately be returned. And DON'T go around suggesting that one should avoid references on principle! That kind of brain-dead thinking is called 'optimizing for incompetence' and it's the worst sin a programmer can commit.

Comment: First of all, the question isn't "how to add values to [an array ref]". There's no mention of reference at all in the question! What a liar you are! It only mentions lists, a commonly used (but incorrect) name for arrays.

Comment: Re "So DON'T assume the refs will immediately be returned." I didn't. I said that's one of two possible reasons to use references in that code, and that in both cases, they variables aren't needed.

Comment: Re "And DON'T go around suggesting that one should avoid references on principle!" I never said that to avoid references. I only said to avoid needless code. If you've seen any of my answer, you very well know that I don't "optimize for incompetence". I'll use the right code for the job, and explain it if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You say "list", but you mean "array". It helps if you start by actually using arrays!

```
my (@xs, @ys);
while (my $line = <IN>){
    chomp ($line);
    my ($x, $y) = split (/,/,$line);
    push @xs, $x;
    push @ys, $y;
}

my $xs = \@xs;
my $ys = \@ys;
```

Comment: Yeah I started like this. I wasn't aware of the use of `\@array`! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since the latest release of [`Text::CSV_XS`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ehmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.04/CSV_XS.pm#fragment) by Merijn Brand (aka Tux), it does allow the use of the **text/csv fragment identifiers** as specified in [RFC7111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111). This makes it super simple to grab a specific fragment of a csv-file.

This code is super simple now:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS ('csv');

my $infile = 'foobar.csv';

my @column_1 = map {$_->[0]} @{ csv(in => $infile, fragment => 'col=1') };
my @column_2 = map {$_->[0]} @{ csv(in => $infile, fragment => 'col=2') };
```

The `csv` function returns a reference to an array_of_arrays. Hence the dereferencing `@{…}` needed for the `map` operator.

The `csv` function (for those that do not want to do OOP) takes a number of arguments:

- **in =>**

  this specifies the input, in this case the input-file. No need to do all the fancy checking or working with file-handles. All is being taken care off.
- **fragment =>**

  this takes either one off the following selectors: 'row', 'col' or 'cell'and a range.

  - row=1;5-7;10-*

    means: row 1, then 5 thru 7 and finally all from 10 till the end
  - col=2;8-12

    means: column 2, and 8 thru 12
  - cell=3,4-8,15

    returns a block from 12 rows and 6 columns, starting at cell 3,4 (column 3, row 4).

WARNING: Never try to rely on your own cleverness when parsing csv files, too many times people fall in that trap, only realising afterwards that some columns suddenly contain comma's them self.

Comment: You might want to explain how that is working. What does the 'fragment' do and what is inside the arrayref that `csv()` is returning?

Answer (score 1):

Though Theo's answer is pretty perfect, it still reads the file twice

Using Spreadsheet::Read (and underneath Text::CSV_XS) even easier:

```
use Spreadsheet::Read;

my $ss   = ReadData ("file.csv");
my @col1 = @{$ss->[1]{cell}[1]}; unshift @col1; # SS = 1-base [0] does not contain a cell
my @col2 = @{$ss->[1]{cell}[2]}; unshift @col2;
```

Using Text::CSV_XS, but reading the file only once

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );

my $col_1_2  = csv (in => "file.csv", fragment => "col=1;2");
my @column_1 = map {$_->[0]} @$col_1_2;
my @column_2 = map {$_->[1]} @$col_1_2;
```

Comment: I first started with fragment=>'cell=1,1-2,*' --- but that didn't work, you might check with RFC7111 and see if I misinterpreted it or if it is a bug. After that attempt, I went for the single column selection instead. You're right, you can easy;ly grab two rows at the same time.